# Error al insertar datos a MySQL usando PHP y AJAX. (NO jQuery)

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Clase PHP donde hago la conexión a la Base de Datos

```
<?php 

    class Buscador
    {
        var $host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $pass = 'chachin', $db = 'employee', $conexion = 'Se conecto',
            $conexion_i = "No se Conecto correctamente", $db_c = 'Se encontro a la DB', $db_i = 'No se encontro la BD';


        function Conectar()
        {
            if (!@mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass)) {
                print $this->conexion_i;
            } else {
                if(!@mysql_select_db($this -> db)) {
                    print $this->db_i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Archivo Ajax donde tengo la función de insertar a la BD

```
function Buscador(){
    var xmlhttp=false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function enviarDatosEmpleado(){

    //recogemos los valores de los inputs
    aidi=document.nuevo_empleado.id.value;
    nom=document.nuevo_empleado.nombre.value;
    ape=document.nuevo_empleado.apellido.value;
    proy=document.nuevo_empleado.proyecto.value;
    fe=document.nuevo_empleado.fecha.value;

    //instanciamos el objetoAjax
    ajax=Buscador();

    //uso del medotod POST
    //archivo que realizará la operacion
    //registro.php
    ajax.open("POST", "registro.php",true);
    //cuando el objeto XMLHttpRequest cambia de estado, la función se inicia
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
         c.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    //enviando los valores a registro.php para que inserte los datos
    ajax.send("id"+aidi+"&nombre="+nom+"&apellido="+ape+"&proyecto="+proy+"&fecha="+fe)
}
```

finalmente el formulario de los datos

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$c = new Buscador;
$c -> Conectar();    
session_start();



if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    $html = <<<html
    <form name="nuevo_empleado" action="" onsubmit="enviarDatosEmpleado(); return false">
            <h2>Nuevo empleado</h2>
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td><td><label><input name="id" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombres</td><td><label><input name="nombre" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellido</td><td><label><input type="text" name="apellido"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Proyecto</td><td><label><input name="proyecto" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fecha</td><td><label><input name="fecha" type="text" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Grabar" /></label></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </form>


html;
    echo $html;
}else{
    echo'<a style="font-family:arial;color:red;font-size:18px" href="login.html">Inicie sesion para ver esta pagina</a>';
}
?>
```

Archivo registro.php el que se encarga de hacer el query de inserción a la base de datos

```
<?php

include("config.php");
// para no mantener la sesion de MySQL abierta
// se utilize solamente en los archivos
$c = new Buscador;
$c -> Conectar();

//variables POST
$aidi=$_POST['id'];
$nom=$_POST['nombre'];
$ape=$_POST['apellido'];
$proy=$_POST['proyecto'];
$fe=$_POST['fecha'];

//registra los datos del empleados
$sql="INSERT INTO employee_details (id, nombre, apellido, proyecto, fecha) VALUES ('$aidi','$nom', '$ape', '$proy', '$fe')";
mysql_query($sql,$con) or die('Error. '.mysql_error());
?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Perdon, estas mezclando, Html y PHP en el mismo archivo??

Comment: Tienes que añadir más detalles: ¿qué es lo que falla?¿qué errores recibes?¿qué es registro.php?¿es un error de conexión o a la hora de insertar? Porque si se conecta bien y el problema es que no se inserta bien, entonces falta código esencial para saber dónde está el error y por qué sucede

Comment: Todo apunta a un error en registro.php,si pones el código será mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Lo único que muestras relacionado con Mysql es un método de conexión desde PHP; es dificil contestar "Error al insertar datos a MySQL [...]" sólo con lo que pones. ¿Dónde y cómo haces la inserción en Mysql?

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios, me falto agregar el archivo registro.php el que se encarga de realizar la conexión ala Base de datos y hace la inserción con los datos que obtengo mediante GET. El problema es que no me da un error solamente no hace nada el código, presiono el botón de guardar y no envía los datos a la BD.espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: @user1396620 El código de registro.php puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL, te recomendaría que lo actualizases y utilizases MySQLi o PDO con sentencias preparadas en lugar de funciones mysql_* (que han sido deprecadas)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, he conseguido que me funcione en local corrigiendo dos cosas en tu código JavaScript (aunque eso no quita que pueda haber errores en el código de registro.php y que debas corregir los problemas de seguridad con la inyección SQL). Los errores son:

1. **El formato de los parámetros es incorrecto**. Este es tu código:

   ```
   //enviando los valores a registro.php para que inserte los datos
   ajax.send("id"+aidi+"&nombre="+nom+"&apellido="+ape+"&proyecto="+proy+"&fecha="+fe)
   ```

   si te fijas, después del parámetro `id` falta el `=`. Eso va a hacer que no se envíen bien los parámetros y que el PHP te falle. El código correcto sería así:

   ```
   //enviando los valores a registro.php para que inserte los datos
   ajax.send("id="+aidi+"&nombre="+nom+"&apellido="+ape+"&proyecto="+proy+"&fecha="+fe)
   ```
2. **No estás pasando los parámetros de manera correcta**. Tienes que especificar en la cabecera de la petición AJAX que lo que estás enviando es un formulario para que los parámetros se envíen de manera correcta por POST. Esto lo puedes hacer añadiendo la siguiente línea:

   ```
   ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   ```

Una vez corregidos esos dos errores, la función `enviarDatosEmpleado` queda así y funciona bien:

```
function enviarDatosEmpleado(){

    //recogemos los valores de los inputs
    aidi=document.nuevo_empleado.id.value;
    nom=document.nuevo_empleado.nombre.value;
    ape=document.nuevo_empleado.apellido.value;
    proy=document.nuevo_empleado.proyecto.value;
    fe=document.nuevo_empleado.fecha.value;

    //instanciamos el objetoAjax
    ajax=Buscador();

    //uso del medotod POST
    //archivo que realizará la operacion
    //registro.php
    ajax.open("POST", "registro.php",true);
    //cuando el objeto XMLHttpRequest cambia de estado, la función se inicia
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4) {
         console.log( ajax.responseText );
        }
    }
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //enviando los valores a registro.php para que inserte los datos
    ajax.send("id="+aidi+"&nombre="+nom+"&apellido="+ape+"&proyecto="+proy+"&fecha="+fe)
}
```

---

**Edición tras revisar todo el código**

Además de los errores especificados arriba que hacían que no funcionase el código JavaScript, he encontrado otra serie de errores que hacían que no funcionara el código. Puede que alguno ocurriera porque hayas compartido una versión simplificada de tu código.

He replicado tu base de datos y usado los ficheros que compartistes y, tras realizar los siguientes cambios, el código me funciona e inserta en la base de datos sin problemas:

- **Incluye el fichero JavaScript en el fichero PHP**. Ahora mismo `guardarEmp.php` sólo muestra el formulario, pero no incluye el ficheor `ajax.php`, lo que hace que la función `EnviarDatosEmpleado` no se llame correctamente y falle.

  En guardarEmp.php, añade esto antes del formulario:

  ```
  <script src="./ajax.js"></script>
  ```
- **Tienes un error tipográfico cuando asignas la variable `p`**. Has cambiado la manera en la que se leen las variables (antes tenías `aidi`, `nom`, `ape`, `proy` y `fe`, pero ahora tienes `id`, `n`, `a`, `p`, y `f`). Al crear `p` has cometido un fallo tipográfico porque pones nuevo_empleadi:

  ```
  p = document.nuevo_empleadi.proyecto.value;
  ```

  debería ser nuevo_emplead**o**:

  ```
  p = document.nuevo_empleado.proyecto.value;
  ```
- **Has cambiado los nombres de las variables, pero sigues usando los nombres antiguos** en lugar de los nuevos. Esto está relacionado con lo anterior, ahora lees las variables de una manera diferente y tienen nombres diferentes, entonces esta línea:

  ```
  ajax.send("id="+aidi+"&nombre="+nom+"&apellido="+ape+"&proyecto="+proy+"&fecha="+fe);
  ```

  ya no tiene sentido porque no tienes `aidi`, `nom`, etc. sino `id`, `n`, etc. Cambia los nombres de las variables:

  ```
  ajax.send("id="+id+"&nombre="+n+"&apellido="+a+"&proyecto="+p+"&fecha="+f);
  ```

Con estos tres cambios (más los dos explicados arriba), la petición AJAX ya se realiza correctamente, pero ahora se obtiene un error en PHP. Así que hay un error en `registro.php`:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Has cambiado las funciones `mysql_*` (que ya no se usan) por `mysqli_*`, lo que es **un buen paso (pero no suficiente para evitar inyección SQL, tienes que usar consultas preparadas)** que ha hecho que aparezca este error.

El método `mysqli_query` necesita dos parámetros: el primero sería la conexión y el segundo la cadena SQL que quieres ejecutar. El problema que tienes ahora es que no guardas la conexión en ningún sitio, lo primero sería modificar `config.php` para que se guarde la conexión una vez establecida:

1. Añade `$conn = null` a la lista de variables de la clase `Buscador`
2. Asigna la conexión a la variable `$conn`

Al final config.php se vería algo como esto:

```
<?php

class Buscador
{
    var $conn = null, $host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $pass = '', $db = 'stackoverflow', $conexion = 'Se conecto',
        $conexion_i = "No se Conecto correctamente", $db_c = 'Se encontro a la DB', $db_i = 'No se encontro la BD';


    function Conectar(){
      $conex = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass);
      $this->conn = $conex;
        if(!@$conex){
            print $this->conexion_i;
        }else{
            if (!@mysqli_select_db($conex,$this->db)) {
                print $this->db_i;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Entonces lo único que te quedaría por hacer es pasar la conexión a `mysqli_query` como el primer parámetro en `registro.php`:

```
mysqli_query($c->conn, $sql) or die('ERROR. '.mysqli_error());
```

Et voilà! Ya funciona todo sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las correcciones, pero ya actualice mi codigo y sigue sin funcionar, no me marcar ningun codigo de error ni nada, ya lo modifique de todas las maneras posibles y no me quiere funcionar, no se si sea un error local

Comment: @user1396620 Ok, luego le hecho un ojo cuando salga del trabajo. Los problemas de AJAX se solucionaron en local con los cambios que indico. Miraré a ver si hay algo con el PHP. ¿podrías compartir la estructura de la tabla employee_details?

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias, mira adjunte los archivos que estoy usando de los cuales tengo el error en este link de google drive, si puedes checarlos y ayudarme te agradeceria mucho.                                          https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqnePaCM182blRpMFZvVW11U0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @user1396620 He editado la pregunta con una lista de los cambios a hacer (apenas 3-4) para que te funcione todo. Parte del problema es que estabas modificando el código conforme te íbamos dando soluciones y eso estaba añadiendo nuevos problemas.

Comment: Te quedaría por corregir el problema con la inyección SQL, pero eso ya es otro tema completamente diferente que deberías tratar cuanto antes mejor.

Comment: muchias gracias por la ayuda Alvaro, une pregunta usando mysqli en vez de mysql, con esto evito la inyeccion SQL?

Comment: @user1396620 Eso se haría usando sentencias preparadas. Puedes leer un artículo en español sobre el tema en la página oficial de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes con la consutla que estas haciendo. Al meter la variables entre comillas simple, te esta dando el error. Prueba con esto

```
$sql="INSERT INTO employee_details (id, nombre, apellido, proyecto, fecha) VALUES ('".$aidi."','".$nom."', '".$ape."', '".$proy."', '".$fe."')";
```

Comment: La variable $sql está entre comillas dobles, las comillas simples de dentro no deberían afectar.